# How can I point my domain to a host without turning over the nameservers?

Tags: dns, webserver, web-hosting, domain-name, web

I have a domain name on GoDaddy, and a site hosted on Network Solutions. Not my choices -- I'm helping out a family member who already has that arrangement.

Currently, the domain's nameserver records just point directly to NetSol's nameservers, and the NetSol hosting package understands that the domain will refer to it. Works fine. But I want to set custom MX records, which means using GoDaddy's nameservers.

I Googled this issue, and the solution seems to be to simply create A records that point to the host's IP address. But I tried that -- using the IP address provided by NetSol's config suggestions, which do line up to the IP I see when I ping the domain -- and it resulted in the domain failing to resolve.

I would really appreciate someone giving me a tip here. What could I have done wrong? What am I supposed to do? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why can you not set MX records on NetSol's DNS server if that is where the domain is delegated to? Why would you alter the A record if you want to add MX records?

Comment: NetSol don't provide any mechanism for editing DNS records on domains that aren't registered with them; all I can do is tell the hosting package that a domain will point to it. I need to change the A records because once the domain is using GoDaddy's nameservers, something has to tell it where the host is.

Comment: You can use custom MX record without using go daddy's name servers I have done so in the past

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is the functionality split here.  There are three parts.  There's a registrar function, a DNS hosting function, and a Web hosting function.  Now you want to add a Mail hosting function.

Based on what you said, you are using GoDaddy for the registrar function and NetSol for the DNS hosting function.  That means you use NetSol to add/remove A records, as that's where you have the DNS function.  There is an A record in their DNS panel that points to an IP address that goes over to NetSol's web hosting platform.  All you need to do is add a MX record that points to the Mail hosting platform similar to that A record for 'www' that points to the Web hosting platform.  Your Mail host supplies the MX record you need to put in.